# 24 bit color themes in vim/neovim in linux subsystem for windows

Tags: vim, colors, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Right now colors in vim are all wrong.

[image]

As you can see I've tried `wsl-terminal` `con-emu` and settings colors in default terminal application to match solarized theme.

All terminals (except conemu) use correct solarized colors, but all of them use them in a wrong way in vim/neovim.

Note that I've tried to switch-off `termguicolors` option. Colors change, but they are still wrong.

I've found the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1706), but I don't know if this is related to this issue.

Have anyone being able to set the 24-bit colors correctly in any of the terminals in windows in vim/neovim?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a fix for it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it worked for me last time I used it. Don't remember how I solved it though. But you could try windows terminal preview, it's probably working there.

Comment: I've managed to fix this issue with the following settings:
.vimrc
set termguicolors
set t_ut= 
set background=dark 

.tmux.conf (not sure if the second option is necessary)
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"                                                                                                                                                                                                   set -ga terminal-overrides ",*256col*:Tc"

TERM variable is equal to "xterm-256color"